# Which version number scheme to use when temporarily extending an open source tool?

Tags: version-number

Assume I want to change an open source library and use it in more than one project, e.g.
company C uses library L version 1.0 with license apache-2. 
The company actually uses a fixed version of it. 
They send the fixes to the original developer of L but want to use the fixed version before there is an official public version.

The license should allow this. 
But which version number to use on the temporarily fixed L.

- 1.1?
- 1.0.1?
- 1.0.temp.1?

or something different?

The idea is that there is eventually an public new version and the company should be abel to use it by just changing the version number.

Comment: Please read about semantic versioning at http://www.semver.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rename the package for internal use. Maybe ourL or something like that.

Another way is what someone else did: A friend of mine patched mpg123 in a time it was only barely maintained and called his fork mpg123-thor. He included everything from upstream but with his own patchsets. Now these patches are all in the current mpg123. His patchset based on mpg123-0.59r he called mpg123-0.59r-thor6 (sixth version of the patchset).
http://thomas.orgis.org/mpg123-thor/

Comment: You see this sometimes in patch-heavy Linux distros, where you'll have a version like `foo-1.2.3-debian-p2`, which is the second Debian patched release on top of foo v1.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to have any conflict or confusion about the version, thus you should use a number that won't cause any. And you can achieve that adding a further sequence to version numbers.

eg:
If the project numbers the version based on

1. two sequences (eg. 1.0, 1.1), I would number it 1.0.1;
2. three sequences (eg. 1.0.2, 1.2.0), I would number your version as 1.0.2.1;
3. four sequences (eg. 1.0.3.2, 1.2.4.2), I would number your version as 1.0.3.2.X, where X is one or two letters not among A (alpha), B (beta), F (final), R (release), RC (release candidate), a dash and a number. You could use for example IR (internal release) or SP (submitted patch) or CP (candidate patch).

Nothing prevents you to add a sequence even for an existing four (or n-th) sequences versioning schema, however you should try to make it easy to use it, and allow people share that information cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 1.0.1

However, the answer depends on the versioning scheme used by the upstream library L maintainers and your package manager (e.g. RPM, Debian, etc), if you are using one.

If the upstream library maintainers use the versioning scheme a.b.c, then I would add an additional field to make it a.b.c.D. That way you will never have a local version conflict with an upstream version. Also take into account, if applicable, how your package manager determines which version is greater.

The [Yocto Project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/), which helps build embedded Linux distributions, seems to typically add a dash and version at the end for downstream changes.

For example, the upstream package/library version is 1.0. You patch the package wit Yocto and update the version from 1.0 to 1.0-1. In the case of Linux library file names, I would name it `/lib/yourlibname.so.1.0.1` since dashes in library file versions is not very common.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this approach:

1. I check what is the versioning scheme used by the project I patch
2. I collect the version number I am patching
3. I check what is (or what will be) the likely next version number after the one I will patching
4. I create a new version using the scheme used by the project such that it will be resolved as a version after the current and before the next version, eventually tagging it as being a "patched" version with a "patch-1", "patch-2" trailing qualifier if this works out ok for the project versioning scheme

In general, I am not renaming the project packages nor their namespaces otherwise to ensure that --if and when-- my patch is integrated in a future version I can just use again the standard version without any code changes.

... unless I want to release this patched version on a public package repository (e.g. Maven, Rubygems, Pypi, etc) in which case I keep the code and namespaces as-is and I create a new package name typically by prefixing or suffixing the package name with my name, project, company or something differentiating.

As a side note, the Apache 2.0 allows this but also requires tracking changes as described in section [4) Redistribution](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html):

> (b) You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating that You changed the files; and ...